# Writing $w_b$ in terms of $w_a$

Tags: substitution

Blanking out on this.. if I have $w_a = \sqrt{\frac km}$ and $w_b = \sqrt{\frac k{2m}}$, how can i rewrite $w_b$ in terms of $w_a$? Would it just be $\frac1{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\frac km}$?

Comment: Hello HokieFan7, can you please use $LATEX$? Thanks :-)

Comment: Yes, so $w_b=\frac{w_a}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Cool, thank you guys. I'll make sure to learn LATEX

Answer (score 1):

$w_a=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ and $w_b=\sqrt{\frac{k}{2m}}$

But $w_b=\sqrt{\frac{k}{2m}}=\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{m}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\times\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}m_a$

So you are right.